# How to preload versioned files for performance enhancement in HTML?

Tags: html, angular, primeng, pagespeed, lighthouse

Various tools (Google Lighthouse, PageSpeed, etc.) suggest preloading key requests via `<link rel=preload>` to increase web site performance. For static files whose filename is known and does not change everything is clear. However, how can I specify a **versioned** file (`https://www.example.org/primeicons.e12e3d4e5dfc6a78e9ee.ttf`) with changing filenames in the link with the preload hint? In my specific case, it is the [PrimeIcons](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/primeicons.xhtml) font from [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of *working* alternatives, I finally changed the value of the `outputHashing` attribute from `all` to `bundles` in the `angular.json` file, and additionally included `<link rel="preload" href="primeicons.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>` in the `<head>` section of `index.html`.

For the assets, which are served without hash now, this may cause a cache issue after re-deploys in production, but I can personally accept that.